# How to squash (merge with next one) commit during rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

This is my pseudo tree:

```
A---B---C---D (master)
```

I started interactive rebase from the root: `git rebase --root -i` and set `edit` command for all commits. Here is example:

```
e b83fa60 Initial content (A)
e 9a82ddf Update license information (B)
e fa8cb80 Rewrite readme (C)
e 0525f07 Update email address (D)
```

Now I've stopped at B during rebase:

```
A---B---C---D (master)
    ^
```

At this point I want to "merge" or "squash" B with the next C commit. How can I do it?

Comment: Why would you want to merge or squash your commits while editing the commit message?

Comment: Because I'm already on ~30 commit starting from root and I don't want to start the process anew. Anyway I just want to know if I can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git rebase --continue` will stop you at the next `e` commit which is C, then `git reset HEAD^ && git add . && git commit --amend` will squash current(C) with previous (B). Although I would personally simply continue rebase and redo again with marking C as `s` or `f` - much simpler and faster.